# AVPlayer Cannot dismiss the View

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a feature that allows users to watch video.

With the code below it animate the video player onto the screen and it include an AVPlayer into the video view and start playing video clip.

However when I press dismissButton it does not work. It only hides dismissButton.

I appreciate any help that lead me to solve this problem.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class VideoPlayerView: UIView {


    let activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        let aiv = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)
        aiv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        aiv.startAnimating()
        return aiv
    }()

    lazy var pausePlayButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        let image = UIImage(named: "pauseButton")
        button.setImage(image, for: UIControlState())
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.tintColor = .white
        button.isHidden = true

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePause), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()

    var isPlaying = false

    func handlePause() {
        if isPlaying {
            player?.pause()
            pausePlayButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "playVideoButton"), for: UIControlState())
        } else {
            player?.play()
            pausePlayButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pauseButton"), for: UIControlState())
        }

        isPlaying = !isPlaying
    }

    let controlsContainerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 1)
        return view
    }()

    let dismissButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        let image = UIImage(named: "closeVideoButton")
        button.setImage(image, for: UIControlState())
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.tintColor = .white
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(pressButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()

    func pressButton(button: UIButton) {
        controlsContainerView.removeFromSuperview()

        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }




    let currentTimeLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "0:00"
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
        return label
    }()

    lazy var videoSlider: UISlider = {
        let slider = UISlider()
        slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        slider.minimumTrackTintColor = .white
        slider.maximumTrackTintColor = .lightGray
        slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "thumb"), for: UIControlState())

        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSliderChange), for: .valueChanged)

        return slider
    }()

    func handleSliderChange() {
        print(videoSlider.value)

        if let duration = player?.currentItem?.duration {
            let totalSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

            let value = Float64(videoSlider.value) * totalSeconds

            let seekTime = CMTime(value: Int64(value), timescale: 1)

            player?.seek(to: seekTime, completionHandler: { (completedSeek) in
            })
        }
    }



    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupPlayerView()

        setupGradientLayer()


        controlsContainerView.frame = frame
        addSubview(controlsContainerView)

        controlsContainerView.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
        activityIndicatorView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        activityIndicatorView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        controlsContainerView.addSubview(pausePlayButton)
        pausePlayButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        pausePlayButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
        pausePlayButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        pausePlayButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

        controlsContainerView.addSubview(currentTimeLabel)
        currentTimeLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        currentTimeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: -2).isActive = true
        currentTimeLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        currentTimeLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true

        controlsContainerView.addSubview(dismissButton)
        dismissButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        dismissButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: -2).isActive = true
        dismissButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        dismissButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true

        controlsContainerView.addSubview(videoSlider)
        videoSlider.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: currentTimeLabel.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        videoSlider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        videoSlider.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dismissButton.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        videoSlider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

        backgroundColor = .black
    }

    var player: AVPlayer?

    fileprivate func setupPlayerView() {
        let urlString = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bunpou-d20ae.appspot.com/o/katoomouto.mp4?alt=media&token=861a0bad-2979-428c-94cf-f86dc9cb63ca"
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            player = AVPlayer(url: url)

            let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
            self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            playerLayer.frame = self.frame

            player?.play()

            player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)

            //track player progress

            let interval = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 2)
            player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { (progressTime) in

                let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(progressTime)
                let secondsString = String(format: "%02d", Int(seconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)))
                let minutesString = String(format: "%02d", Int(seconds / 60))

                self.currentTimeLabel.text = "\(minutesString):\(secondsString)"

                if let duration = self.player?.currentItem?.duration {
                    let durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

                    self.videoSlider.value = Float(seconds / durationSeconds)

                }

            })
        }
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        //this is when the player is ready and rendering frames
        if keyPath == "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges" {
            activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
            controlsContainerView.backgroundColor = .clear
            pausePlayButton.isHidden = false
            isPlaying = true


        }
    }

    fileprivate func setupGradientLayer() {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [-1.4, 0.2]
        controlsContainerView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }



    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class VideoLauncher: NSObject {

    func showVideoPlayer() {
        print("Showing video player animation....")

        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            let view = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            view.frame = CGRect(x: keyWindow.frame.width - 10, y: keyWindow.frame.height - 10, width: 10, height: 10)

            let videoPlayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.height)
            let videoPlayerView = VideoPlayerView(frame: videoPlayerFrame)
            view.addSubview(videoPlayerView)

            keyWindow.addSubview(view)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                view.frame = keyWindow.frame

            }, completion: { (completedAnimation) in
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Include code that shows how the AVPlayer is added as a subview (probably as AVPlayerLayer)...

Comment: Yes I added the code.

Comment: Ok, check the answer, you are not removing the AVPlayerLayer from view hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dismiss button is tapped you remove only `controlsContainerView` from the superview.

```
func pressButton(button: UIButton) { controlsContainerView.removeFromSuperview() }
```

Given how you have things setup I would do the following:

1. you do not need `let view = ...` inside `showVideoPlayer`, but just use `videoPlayerView` and add it like `keyWindow.addSubView(videoPlayerView)`
2. Inside `pressButton` you have to first remove observers from `player` that you added like `player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)`
3. still inside `pressButton` stop the player like `player?.stop()` and then remove `self` from superview like you are doing with `self.removeFromSuperview()`

Notes: I dont like that view itself should be responsible to remove itself from superview. So I would suggest that you have a controller that handles showing/hiding of `VideoPlayerView` and just add a public method to `VideoPlayerView` like `stop` where you would remove all observers of the `player`, stop the `player` so that when controller decides to remove `VideoPlayerView` you will do a nice cleanup

Comment: When I add the method "playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()" I receive the error "the use of unresolved identifier "playerLayer" Do you have any idea for?

Comment: I just did it in a test application and it removed the playerLayer as it should, update the pressButton method to what you currently have

Comment: Also please check where let playerLayer is decleared...is it inside VideoPlayerView class or somewhere else?

Comment: I updated the answer playerLayer is decleared in "VideoLauncher class" .

Comment: In the code you posted it does not seem `playerLayer` is decleared in `VideoLauncher` class...why don't you just do `self.removeFromSuperview()` in `pressButton` method since it doesnt seem you need `VideoPlayerView` after button is pressed

Comment: When i implemented the code The screen becomes white and audio keeps playing .......

Comment: You will have to post whole `VideoLauncher` class code, or at least whole `showVideoPlayer` method and where `videoLayer` is initialized and used.

 Audio does not stop playing because you have to stop AVPlayer before dismissing it...

Comment: Thank youfor your help:)